# Ler Ficheiro java com delimitador

Tags: java, arquivo

Tenho o seguinte ficheiro txt:
38461;Rui Brito;20
34561;Rui Brito;10
31231;Rui Brito;6

**E o seguinte código:**

```
ArrayList<Aluno> listaAlunos = new ArrayList<Aluno>();

public void lerFicheiroPauta(String nomeFicheiro) {
    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(nomeFicheiro));
        sc.useDelimiter("\\; || \n");
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            int número = sc.nextInt();
            String nome = sc.next();
            int nota = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();

            listaAlunos.add(new Aluno(número, nome, nota));

        }
        sc.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Erro na leitura");
        // listaAlunos.clear();
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public String toString() {
    String sc = "";
    for (Aluno a : listaAlunos) {
        sc += a + System.lineSeparator();
    }
    return sc;

}
```

O que acontece é que o resultado é este:
[image: Resultado da execução]

Alguém me pode dar uma ajuda pra ler o ficheiro correctamente sff?

Comment: O que você pretende fazer? ´Separar os valores entre ponto e virgula?